# Ubuntu 20.04: Icons Disappear and Everything Freezes

Tags: 20.04, icons, freeze

I am new to Ubuntu and I have the following problem: Every once in a while, the icons of all open software disappear and nothing works anymore, except closing the software. I can't open the terminal, I can't turn my laptop off properly, nothing.

When I hit the power button once, I get a black screen with ongoing error messages, one of them is as follows:

```
"EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p2): __ext4_find)entry:1531: inode #10750786: comm gmain: reading directory lblock 0"
```

These error messages go on forever, until hard shutdown.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a new Lenovo E15. Can anyone help me with this one? I'm happy to provide more information, just tell me what you need.

Comment: Your SSD got disconnected. Open your laptop, remove the SSD and put it in again.

Comment: Argh. It's a brand-new laptop. Would you think it's worth taking the risk to open it up, take out the SSD and put it back inside? I have zero experience with this and it's possible that I break something. Could it be anything else?